# Horizontal alignment in beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, align, footnotes, footmisc

I have used `beamer` to create a presentation. The problem is that sentences do not start from the right (In the Persian language, we write from right to left). Also, the footnotes text doesn't appear in the bottom of the page.

This is the code that I have used. (If anyone can answer this question with English words instead of Persian, it is rather OK. Please share me your answer.)

```
    \documentclass[11pt,xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames,table}]{beamer}‎
    ‎‎‎\usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{afterpage}

    \usepackage{url}‎‎
    \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usetheme{Warsaw}‎
    \usepackage{graphicx}‎‎
‎    \usefonttheme{serif}‎
    ‎\usepackage{ptext}‎‎
    ‎‎\usepackage[top=3.5cm,right=3cm,bottom=4cm,left=3cm]{geometry}‎  
    ‎\usepackage{amsmath}‎
     ‎\usepackage[marginal,stable,bottom]{footmisc}     % for footnotes‎: ‎marginal‎ -‎-> the same margins as text‎, 

    ‎\usepackage{perpage}                                            
‎    \MakePerPage{footnote}‎
‎    \usepackage{cite}                                                     % for 
    ‎\usepackage{setspace}                                            % for 
‎    \allowdisplaybreaks                                                    
    ‎\usepackage{parskip}      

    ‎\usepackage{xepersian}‎
‎    \settextfont{Yas}‎‎

    ‎\begin{document}‎
    \begin{persian}‎

\title{رعیی}
\author{مد‏ \and ‏‎\\ ‎
استادی}

‎\begin{frame}‎
‎\maketitle‎
‎\end{frame}‎
‎
\everypar{\rightskip\rightmargin}
‎\begin{frame}‎
‎%‎\ptext[1-2]‎‎
‎‎\tableofcontents‎
‎\end{frame}‎
\section{‏‎‎‏ماعل ‎‎\hfill}‎‎
\section{‏مه ‎\hfill}‎‎
‎\subsection{‏حری ‎\hfill}‎‎‎
‎\begin{frame}‎‎‎‎
‎‎‎ ‎\begin{figure}[!htb]‎‎‎
‎\includegraphics[width=11.5‎cm‎]{‎f‎}‎
\caption{‎‏‎‏سی‎
 \LTR‎footnote{‎Pr‎‎}‎‎‎‎
. ‏نده‎‏
 ‎‎‎\LTRfootnote{‎r‎}‎‎‎‎ .‎
}
‎    \label{fig}‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
    ‎\end{figure}‎‎
    ‎\end{frame}‎
‎
    ‎‎\subsection{‎‏پی ‎\hfill}‎‎‎
    ‎\begin{frame}
‎‎‎ ‎\begin{figure}[!htb]‎‎‎
‎\includegraphics[width=‏10.80‎cm‎]{‎chemort‎}‎
\caption{‎‏‎‏‎بل
  جی.
}
    ‎\label{f}‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
    ‎\end{figure}‎‎
    \end{frame}

    ‎\begin{frame}‎‎‎
    \textcolor{RoyalPurple‎‎‎}{‎‏سی 
 ‎\LTR‎footnote{‎Ci}‎‎‎‎
 ‎بد نوشته میشه. خیلی خیلی  
 ی به ه‌ یلی ‎.‎‏}‎
‎
\vspace{0.1in} 
   ‎‎‎‎\textcolor{orange}{یلیش رامد؟}

\vspace{0.0005in} 
\fontdimen2\font=1pt‎

  ‏همه متنا بد نوشتا بد نوشته میشه همه شون داغوا بد نوشته میشه همه شون داغونه کلا د.نه کلا د.ه میشه همه شون داغونه کلا د. ‎
  ‎\vspace{0.1in}‎
‎‎‎ ‎\begin{figure}[!htb]‎‎‎
‎\includegraphics[width=3.2‎cm‎]{‎chem‎}‎
\caption{‎‏‎‏‎‏حا بد نوشته میشه همه شون داغونه کلا د.ال
‎\LTR‎footnote{‎Rle‎‎‎}‎‎
 ا بد نوشته میشه همه شون داغونه کلا د.
}
    ‎\label{f}‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
    ‎\end{figure}‎‎
    ‎‎\end{frame}‎


    \subsection{ما بد نوشته میشه همه شون داغونه کلا د.ته\hfill}
‎    \begin{frame}‎
    \frametitle{‏ما بد نوشته میشه همه شون داغونهsxsax کلا د.

  ‎‎
‏‎‎‎‎‎‎‎$J‎‎$ : ا بد نوشته میشه همه شون ا بد نوشته میاغونه کلا د.صله از 

\vspace{0.0005in} ‎

    \fontdimen2\font=0.2ex% inter word space‎
    \fontdimen2\font=1pt‎
    ‎‎$‎f‎$‎ ‎‎‎:فرا بد نوشته میشه همه شون داغونه کلا د.ت‎
    \fontdimen2\font=0.2ex% inter word space‎

    \vspace{0.0005in} ‎

‎‎$‎c‎‎$‎ ‎‎‎‎: یه متن کوچولو ی

\vspace{0.0005in} 
‎‎$‎‎\Delta‎‎$‎  : طول متن زیاد میشه

    \vspace{0.0005in} 
    ‎‎$‎‎\Delta ‎‎\alpha‎‎‎‎‎$‎ ‎‏‏: فاصله‌ی کلمه ها زیادهل
    \begin{equation}‎
    ‎\partial‎_t \rho(x) = - \nabla \cdot J(x).
      \end{equation}

    ‎\end{persian‎}‎‎
    ‎\end{document}‎
```

Could any one solve the problem? I really appreciate any answer.

---

This version of the example runs without error please edit this question to say how you want the output to change.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames,table}]{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{ptext}
%\usepackage[top=3.5cm,right=3cm,bottom=4cm,left=3cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[marginal,stable,bottom]{footmisc}     % for footnotes: marginal --> the same margins as text,
%\usepackage{perpage}
%\MakePerPage{footnote}
\usepackage{cite}%                                                     % for
\usepackage{setspace}%                                            % for 
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
%\def\__fontspec_pass_args:nnn#1#2#3{#1#2}{#3}}
\cs_new:Nn \__fontspec_pass_args:nnn
 {
  \IfNoValueTF {#2}
   { \__fontspec_post_arg:w {#1} {#3} }
   { #1 {#2} {#3} }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand \__fontspec_post_arg:w { m m O{} }
 { #1 {#3} {#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
\begin{persian}

\title{رعیی}
\author{مد‏ \and ‏\\ 
استادی}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

%\everypar{\rightskip\rightmargin}
\begin{frame}
%\ptext[1-2]
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{‏‏ماعل \hfill}
\section{‏مه \hfill}
\subsection{‏حری \hfill}
\begin{frame}
 \begin{figure}[!htb]
%\includegraphics[width=11.5cm]{f}
\caption{‏‏سی
 \LTRfootnote{Pr}
. ‏نده‏
 \LTRfootnote{r} .
}
    \label{fig}
    \end{figure}
    \end{frame}

    \subsection{‏پی \hfill}
    \begin{frame}
 \begin{figure}[!htb]
%\includegraphics[width=‏10.80cm]{chemort}
\caption{‏‏بل
  جی.
}
    \label{f}
    \end{figure}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    \textcolor{RoyalPurple}{‏سی 
 \LTRfootnote{Ci}
 بد نوشته میشه. خیلی خیلی  
 ی به ه‌ یلی .‏}

\vspace{0.1in} 
   \textcolor{orange}{یلیش رامد؟}

\vspace{0.0005in} 
\fontdimen2\font=1pt

  ‏همه متنا بد نوشتا بد نوشته میشه همه شون داغوا بد نوشته میشه همه شون داغونه کلا د.نه کلا د.ه میشه همه شون داغونه کلا د. 


\vspace{0.1in}
 \begin{figure}[!htb]


%\includegraphics[width=3.2cm]{chem}
\caption{‏‏‏حا بد نوشته میشه همه شون داغونه کلا د.ال
\LTRfootnote{Rle}
 ا بد نوشته میشه همه شون داغونه کلا د.
}
    \label{f}
    \end{figure}
   \end{frame}
    \subsection{ما بد نوشته میشه همه شون داغونه کلا د.ته\hfill}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{‏ما بد نوشته میشه همه شون داغونهsxsax کلا د.


‏$J$ : ا بد نوشته میشه همه شون ا بد نوشته میاغونه کلا د.صله از 

}

\vspace{0.0005in} 

    \fontdimen2\font=0.2ex% inter word space
    \fontdimen2\font=1pt
    $f$ :فرا بد نوشته میشه همه شون داغونه کلا د.ت
    \fontdimen2\font=0.2ex% inter word space

    \vspace{0.0005in} 

$c$ : یه متن کوچولو ی

\vspace{0.0005in} 
$\Delta$  : طول متن زیاد میشه

    \vspace{0.0005in} 
    $\Delta \alpha$ ‏‏: فاصله‌ی کلمه ها زیادهل
    \begin{equation}
    \partial_t \rho(x) = - \nabla \cdot J(x).
      \end{equation}

\end{frame}
    \end{persian}

   \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Mostly the problems were package errors in your preamble and illegal control characters, but also the spurious spacing commands  in the document. Having removed those, as stated in comments you can get raggedleft text using `\raggedleft` for example starting the last frame

```
\begin{frame}
\raggedleft
```

produces

[image]

On footnotes, you can not use page footnotes from a caption inside a figure box. You could (presumably, I don't know the `xepersian` package features here) use `\footnotemark` in the caption and `\footnotetext{...}` somehere outside the figure, however I would simply remove the footnotes, really they don't work in a presentation. The beamer manual says:

> First a word of warning: Using footnotes is usually not a good idea. They 
>   disrupt the flow of reading.

If you do want to use footnotes in beamer despite that warning it is probably best to use the beamer commands rather than other footnote packages.

```
\documentclass[11pt,xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames,table}]{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{ptext}
%\usepackage[top=3.5cm,right=3cm,bottom=4cm,left=3cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[marginal,stable,bottom]{footmisc}     % for footnotes: marginal --> the same margins as text,
%\usepackage{perpage}
%\MakePerPage{footnote}
\usepackage{cite}%                                                     % for
\usepackage{setspace}%                                            % for 
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
%\def\__fontspec_pass_args:nnn#1#2#3{#1#2}{#3}}
\cs_new:Nn \__fontspec_pass_args:nnn
 {
  \IfNoValueTF {#2}
   { \__fontspec_post_arg:w {#1} {#3} }
   { #1 {#2} {#3} }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand \__fontspec_post_arg:w { m m O{} }
 { #1 {#3} {#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
\begin{persian}

\title{رعیی}
\author{مد‏ \and ‏\\ 
استادی}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

%No never do this\everypar{\rightskip\rightmargin}
\begin{frame}
%\ptext[1-2]
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{‏‏ماعل }
\section{‏مه }
\subsection{‏حری }
\begin{frame}
 \begin{figure}[!htb]
%\includegraphics[width=11.5cm]{f}
\caption{‏‏سی
 \LTRfootnote{Pr}
. ‏نده‏
 \LTRfootnote{r} .
}
    \label{fig}
    \end{figure}
    \end{frame}

    \subsection{‏پی }
    \begin{frame}
 \begin{figure}[!htb]
%\includegraphics[width=‏10.80cm]{chemort}
\caption{‏‏بل
  جی.
}
    \label{f}
    \end{figure}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    \textcolor{RoyalPurple}{‏سی 
 \LTRfootnote{Ci}
 بد نوشته میشه. خیلی خیلی  
 ی به ه‌ یلی .‏}

\vspace{0.1in} 
   \textcolor{orange}{یلیش رامد؟}

% what??? \vspace{0.0005in} 
\fontdimen2\font=1pt

  ‏همه متنا بد نوشتا بد نوشته میشه همه شون داغوا بد نوشته میشه همه شون داغونه کلا د.نه کلا د.ه میشه همه شون داغونه کلا د. 


\vspace{0.1in}
 \begin{figure}[!htb]


%\includegraphics[width=3.2cm]{chem}
\caption{‏‏‏حا بد نوشته میشه همه شون داغونه کلا د.ال
\LTRfootnote{Rle}
 ا بد نوشته میشه همه شون داغونه کلا د.
}
    \label{f}
    \end{figure}
   \end{frame}
    \subsection{ما بد نوشته میشه همه شون داغونه کلا د.ته}
    \begin{frame}
\raggedleft
    \frametitle{‏ما بد نوشته میشه همه شون داغونهsxsax کلا د.


‏$J$ : ا بد نوشته میشه همه شون ا بد نوشته میاغونه کلا د.صله از 

}

% what??? \vspace{0.0005in} 

%?    \fontdimen2\font=0.2ex% inter word space
    \fontdimen2\font=1pt
%?    $f$ :فرا بد نوشته میشه همه شون داغونه کلا د.ت
%?    \fontdimen2\font=0.2ex% inter word space

% what???     \vspace{0.0005in} 

$c$ : یه متن کوچولو ی

% what??? \vspace{0.0005in} 
$\Delta$  : طول متن زیاد میشه

% what???     \vspace{0.0005in} 
    $\Delta \alpha$ ‏‏: فاصله‌ی کلمه ها زیادهل
    \begin{equation}
    \partial_t \rho(x) = - \nabla \cdot J(x).
      \end{equation}

\end{frame}
    \end{persian}

   \end{document}
```

Comment: After running your second code, footnotes texts are not shown!

Comment: @saranj yes as I said, you can not use `\footnote` from out of a caption.

Comment: What can I use out of caption to show footnote?  your code doesn't how footnotes in the caption too